# when to use ScreenAdapter and when Screen

Tags: libgdx

From the docs, ScreenAdapter is convenience implementation of Screen. I am not sure when is it better to implement Screen and when extend ScreenAdapter. What are the specific benefits of doing it one way or another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ScreenAdapter` implements `Screen`, so the result in practice will be the same. The code will look a bit different though.

The *convenience* of `ScreenAdapter` is that it provides a default empty implementation. So you don't have to `@override` methods that you don't need, keeping your code cleaner.

However, java doesn't support extending multiple classes. For example you can't extend both `ScreenAdapter` and `InputAdapter`. In that case you'd have to choose which one to extend and you'd have to implement (write code even you dont need the method) the other.

Make sure to have a look at the source and see for your self, it's nothing magical:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/ScreenAdapter.java

That said; having the convenience of not having to implement the methods, might make you forget about those methods. For example, if you implement `ApplicationListener` then you are confronted with the life cycle of your application, but if you extend `ApplicationAdapter` then it can be easy to forget about e.g. the `resize` or `dispose` method. Therefor, personally, I usually use `ApplicationListener` when creating a tutorial and such. On the other hand when I need to write a quick test or alike, I use `ApplicationAdapter`.